# Any recommendations for a command-line download manager?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, downloads

Any command-line download accelerator/manager recommendations for Ubuntu 11.04? I tried some programs like

1. [Axel](http://wilmer.gaa.st/main.php/axel.html)
2. wget/curl

I wanted to know if there are any command-line download managers which have a "resume download" feature.

#### edit

*1st download:*

```
 axel -a -n 10 http://yui.zenfs.com/theater/f2esummit2011-tso.mp4
 Initializing download:
 http://yui.zenfs.com/theater/f2esummit2011-tso.mp4 File size:
 316943546 bytes Opening output file f2esummit2011-tso.mp4 State file
 found: 5412634 bytes downloaded, 311530912 to go. Starting download

 Connection 1 unexpectedly closed                                      
 ] Connection 2 unexpectedly closed                                    
 ] Connection 9 unexpectedly closed                                    
 ] Connection 6 unexpectedly closed                                    
 ] Connection 8 unexpectedly closed                                    
 ] Connection 3 unexpectedly closed                                    
 ] Connection 5 unexpectedly closed                                    
 ] [  6%] [0    1    2    3    4    5    6     7    8    9   ] [ 
 58.3KB/s] [ 1h22]
```

This is what I did: I ran two simultaneous downloads. But with Axel, I'm getting the below error:
Segmentation Error

*2nd download:*

```
axel -v -a -n -10 http://yui.zenfs.com/theater/f2esummit2011-glass.mp4
Initializing download: http://yui.zenfs.com/theater/f2esummit2011-glass.mp4
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: `axel` resumes downloads if you stop them halfway and redownload later

Comment: @user7044 If you're getting a segfault in the 2nd download, then that's probably a bug you should file. Failed downloads should make the program quit gracefully, not crash.

Comment: Added a bug for axel; Here is the Bug details for this Axel issue; https://alioth.debian.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=413085&aid=313338&group_id=100070

Answer (score 10):

`wget`, that is installed by default, has such a feature through the `-c` option:

```
   -c
   --continue
       Continue getting a partially-downloaded file.  This is useful when
       you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of
       Wget, or by another program.

       ...

       Note that -c only works with FTP servers and with HTTP servers that
       support the "Range" header.
```

Comment: Any way to set Download Priority; Or allocate Bandwidth(high/low/medium/normal), I noticed one thing here with wget, when axel is running in parallel(-n with 10 connection), the bandwidth allocation to wget is less than 1.43kbs. Any way to set download/upload limits.

Comment: No, it seems to not support any type of priority. And this is a features of a queuing download manager, that `wget` is not. Regarding bandwidth, see `--limit-rate` in man page.

Answer (score 1):

try aria2c. It is also supported by the firefox flashgot addon

```
sudo apt-get install aria2
```

Answer (score 0):

Axel mostly worked for me, but I can remember a firfox addon

> [firedownload](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firedownload/)

which serves the purpose in most of the cases without command line. I am not sure about resume download stuff. But if you do not care about multi-connection download you can use Opera browser which has an awesome download manager with some extraordinary resuming capabilities. You can even continue resuming stuff which were half downloaded from other softwares.